# Extract specific word of String in bash

Tags: string, bash

I need to extract a particular word from a string in bash.

I have a String "xxx/yyy/zzz/foo.txt" from this string i need to extract "zzz".

```
input="xxx/yyy/zzz/foo.txt"

((length = ${#input} - 8))
subString= {$file:0:$length}
name= $subString | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev
echo $name
```

Here, I got an error like "xxx/yyy/zzz/foo.txt":0:52}: No such file or directory"  at line : subString= {$file:0:$length}

Anyone help on this?

Comment: Basically you want `basename "$(dirname "$input")"`

Comment: How do you identify the word you want? Character 9-11? Character 10 from the end to 12 from the end? Between the last and the second to last `/ `?

Comment: Alternates are: `awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "$input"` OR `grep -oP '.*/\K[^/]*(?=/)' <<< "$input"`. Or with pure bash: `inp1=${input%/*}; echo ${inp1##*/}`

Comment: just focus on your code, `{$file:0:$length}` should be `${file:0:$length}`. This is the cause of your error

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors. http://shellcheck.net is your first friend here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with filename, you can use `basename` and `dirname` commands:

```
$ input="xxx/yyy/zzz/foo.txt"; echo $(basename $(dirname $input))
zzz
```

Comment: Aah, you beat me by half a minute :-P